# how to create datetime object for a specific time in a timezone in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a time that I want users to be reminded of when that time comes in their respective time zone.  It is stored as time field:

```
reminder = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a timezone associated with each user.  It looks like:

```
customer1_timezone = customer1.time_zone #la timezone
customer2_timezone = customer2.time_zone #ny timezone
```

Let's say customer1 and customer2 both have the reminder set to 7am.

How do I indicate 7am for each user relative to their timzone?

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this

```
def user_time(time_value, customer):
    tz = pytz.timezone(customer.time_zone)
    c_tz = pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
    d_tz = c_tz.normalize(c_tz.localize(time_value))
    return tz.normalize(d_tz.astimezone(tz))
```

That would get the time for the customer, then you just need to check it is 7am.  You could use strftime() even for that.  user_time(datetime.now(), customer).strftime("%H") == "07"

Comment: What is the "value"?  I use a timefield as edited above.  How can I convert my timefield into your value field?

Comment: Opps, that 'value' should be 'time_value'

Comment: @Atma: to get an hour from a datetime objet (`user_time()` returns them), use `.hour` attribute.

Comment: @Atma: If `time_value` is from `TimeField` then you should combine it with date before passing to `c_tz.localize()`: `time_value = datetime.combine(datetime.now(c_tz).date(), time_value)`. Note: 7am in `settings.TIME_ZONE` may correspond to a different hour in `customer.time_zone`.